# How do I stop accelerometer from detecting upward/downward motion when the phone is rotated between portrait-landscape modes

Tags: android, rotation, accelerometer, android-orientation

I have 2 booleans `up` and `down` for when I move the phone up and down. The default position of the phone is portrait.

When I rotate the phone to landscape, even though I didn't move the phone downwards, the `down` variable becomes true. Then when I rotate back to portrait, the `up` value becomes true even if the phone doesn't move up.

How do I stop this from happening? I want it so that if the phone is in `up` or `down` mode, it will stay in that mode regardless of the orientation of the phone.

The up-down code:

```
                if (ty > 3.0f) { // go down
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    down = true;
                    up = false;
                }
                else if (ty < -3.0f) { // go up
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    up = true;
                    down = false;
                }

                upVal.setText("Up: " + up);
                downVal.setText("Down: " + down);
```

(I also don't know why it turns green when I move it down even though the `ty` value is positive and vice versa.)

The rotation code:

```
            if( (orientation < 35 || orientation > 325) && rotation!= ROTATION_O){ // PORTRAIT
                rotation = ROTATION_O;
            }
            else if( orientation > 145 && orientation < 215 && rotation!=ROTATION_180){ // REVERSE PORTRAIT
                rotation = ROTATION_180;
            }
            else if(orientation > 55 && orientation < 125 && rotation!=ROTATION_270){ // REVERSE LANDSCAPE
                rotation = ROTATION_270;
            }
            else if(orientation > 235 && orientation < 305 && rotation!=ROTATION_90){ //LANDSCAPE
                rotation = ROTATION_90;
            }
```

Comment: Put the accelerometer at the centre of rotation. Otherwise there will always be a vertical component.

Comment: @SolarMike, can you explain more please? I don't understand what you mean by 'put accelerometer at the centre of rotation'. Is it like put the accelerometer method inside the rotation method?

Comment: Plot the path the sensors move when the phone moves. You must know the location of each sensor.

Comment: @SolarMike, Sorry, I'm still really confused. You mean I have to get the location of the phone relative to the world? I've been told that this is impossible to do with just the accelerometer. I'll have to integrate it twice to get the velocity then position value, which will be very inaccurate anyway. Am I misunderstanding something? I can see the graph of the accelerometer's values in all 3 axis in the settings of the phone, if that's what you mean (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out all I need to do is to unregister and reregister the accelerometer while the phone is rotating and when it stops respectively.

1. Add a gyroscope class like [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-build-an-application-to-test-motion-sensors-in-android/)
2. In MainActivity, add this:

```
        gyroscope.setListener(new Gyroscope.Listener() {
            // on rotation method of gyroscope
            @Override
            public void onRotation(float rx, float ry, float rz) {
                if (rz > 1.0f) {
                    //phone is moving, unregister the accelerometer
                    accelerometer.unregister();

                } else if (rz < -1.0f) {
                    // phone is moving, unregister the accelerometer
                    accelerometer.unregister();

                } else {
                    //phone stops moving, re-register the accelerometer
                    accelerometer.register();
                }
            }
        });
```